# TSQL Group By Column

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

I have a t-sql table listing agreements for multiple locations.

Columns:

- STID = Store ID
- AStatID = Agreement Status ID (1=Active)
- PayModeID = (1=daily, 2=weekly, etc..)
- and then a column for *each* of the PayMode amounts

I am trying to get our monthly *potential* income from active agreements, per store.

This is what I have so far, but I get the error *“Subquery returned more than 1 value”*.

Where am I going wrong?

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
Declare @dPotential Money,
    @wPotential Money,
    @bPotential Money,
    @sPotential Money,
    @mPotential Money,
    @Potential Money;

Set @dPotential = (((Select Agreemnt.DailyRate FROM Agreemnt WHERE Agreemnt.PayModeID = 1 And Agreemnt.AStatID = 1)*365)/12)
Set @wPotential = (((Select Agreemnt.WeeklyRate FROM Agreemnt WHERE Agreemnt.PayModeID = 2 And Agreemnt.AStatID = 1)*52)/12)
Set @bPotential = (((Select Agreemnt.WeeklyRate FROM Agreemnt WHERE Agreemnt.PayModeID = 3 And Agreemnt.AStatID = 1)*52)/12)
Set @sPotential = (((Select Agreemnt.DailyRate FROM Agreemnt WHERE Agreemnt.PayModeID = 4 And Agreemnt.AStatID = 1)*24)/12)
Set @mPotential = ((Select Agreemnt.DailyRate FROM Agreemnt WHERE Agreemnt.PayModeID = 5 And Agreemnt.AStatID = 1)* 12)

Set @Potential = @dPotential + @wPotential + @bPotential + @sPotential + @mPotential

Select Agreemnt.STID, @Potential From Agreemnt 
Group By Agreemnt.STID
```

Comment: one of those queries assigning values to your variables return more than one row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
  a.STID,
  SUM(
    CASE a.PayModeID
      WHEN 1 THEN a.DailyRate * 365 / 12
      WHEN 2 THEN a.WeeklyRate * 52 / 12
      WHEN 3 THEN a.WeeklyRate * 52 / 12
      WHEN 4 THEN a.DailyRate * 24 / 12
      WHEN 5 THEN a.DailyRate * 12
    END ) as Potential
FROM Agreemnt a
WHERE a.AStatID = 1
GROUP BY a.STID
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a data issue. You will need to see which of these returns multiple values and why. Use these qeres to see what the data is:

```
Select * FROM Agreemnt WHERE Agreemnt.PayModeID = 1 And Agreemnt.AStatID = 1
Select * FROM Agreemnt WHERE Agreemnt.PayModeID = 2 And Agreemnt.AStatID = 1
Select * FROM Agreemnt WHERE Agreemnt.PayModeID = 3 And Agreemnt.AStatID = 1
Select * FROM Agreemnt WHERE Agreemnt.PayModeID = 4 And Agreemnt.AStatID = 1
Select * FROM Agreemnt WHERE Agreemnt.PayModeID = 5 And Agreemnt.AStatID = 1
```

Note I used select * here because it is likely one of the other fields in the table is causing the duplicate. To fix will depend on what the data meaning is. It could mean you need to use an aggregate function or an additional where clause.